# How to change the learning rate in Theano back propagation on-the-fly?

Tags: python, theano

I try to implement a back propagation with adaptive learning rate using Theano.

In the `__init__` method of my class I have the following code:

```
# set initial learning rate
self.l_rate = 0.01
# calculate of updates for weights
W_ups = self.W - self.l_rate*gr_W
updates = [(self.W, W_ups)]
self.backprop = theano.function([self.X], self.E, updates=updates)
```

Then I have a `train` method of my class where I have the following code:

```
def train(self, X):
    # get the current error
    c1 = self.backprop(X)

    # update weights interativelly
    for i in range(n_iter):
        c2 = self.backprop(X)
        print c2, self.l_rate
        if c2 >= c1:
            self.l_rate = self.l_rate/10.0
        c1 = c2
    return self.L, self.R
```

From the behavior that I observer it looks to me that reduction of the learning rate in the `train` method (`self.l_rate = self.l_rate/10.0`) is not seen by the back propagation. In more detail, at some point the costs that I try to minimize stop to change, as a result of it I reduce the learning rate but the costs stay the same during the next iterations. As a result of unchanging costs I reduce the learning rate further and further but the costs stay the same.

May it be the case that the computational graph defined in the `__init__` method memorize value of the learning rate and by changing `self.l_rate` I do not change the `backprop` function?

**ADDED**

As recommended in the comment I did the following changes. In `__init__` I have:

```
self.l_rate = theano.shared(value=0.01)
```

In the `train` method I have:

```
self.l_rate.set_value(self.l_rate.eval()/10.0)
```

However, the behavior stays the same (as soon as costs stop to change, reducing the learning rate does not have, the costs stay on the same level).

Comment: Define `l_rate` as a shared variable, and update it using `l_rate.set_values`. Basically same to the last answer I gave.

Comment: @Kh40tiK, thank you for the answer. I have implemented the changes that you have proposed (for details you can check my extended question) but the behavior stay the same.

Comment: since it's a shared variable you should use `self.l_rate.get_value()` instead of `self.l_rate.eval()`, also may be it's better to decrease learning rate by 1/2 instead of directly decreasing by 10. But anyhow, when you change the value of `self.l_rate` it is reflected for sure in the execution of computation graph.